# cache formatting not working

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, cache

I already had problem where my phone was turning on for a while, showing 'apps are optimizing' and 'no storage left'. I had fixed it previously using recovery mode and wiped cache partition. Everything worked perfectly straight away.

However this time I tried already wiping cache partition in the same way about 10 times already and I also tried to manually delete all content of `/cache` using `adb` and `su`, with no success.

Is there anything I could do to fix it?

If this can help, my phone is Nexus 4, running rooted 5.1.1 lollipop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are familiar with fastboot, you could boot or flash [TWRP](https://twrp.me/devices/lgnexus4.html) and format the cache that way.

Download the current TWRP img file, copy it to your fastboot folder, and issue the command

`fastboot boot twrp-3.0.2-0-mako.img`

Once it loads and starts at the main menu, select `Wipes` and then untick everything except Cache and Dalvik cache and execute the wipe and reboot.

If that fails, it might be time to flash a new [factory image](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images).